# $n$th derivatives if $n\notin\Bbb{W}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we have $a^n$ and $n\in\Bbb{W}$ (where $\Bbb W=\{0,1,2,3,4,\cdots\}$), then that means we take $1$ and multiply it by $a$ $n$ times. In addition, following exponent rules, $a^n$ still has meaning if $n\in\Bbb{Q}$ or if $n<0$ even though we can't multiple $1$ by $a$ a negative number of times or a fractional number of times.

If we have $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$, then that means that we differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ $n$ times. Similar to the example above, does $\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}$ have meaning if $n\notin\Bbb{W}$ even though we can't *really* take the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ a fractional or negative number of times? Trying to tackle $\frac{d^{-1}y}{dx^{-1}}$, is this considered the same as $\int y\, dx$?

Comment: As far as I know, $\Bbb W$ isn't standard notation for the set of whole numbers. Typically one writes $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$ or some variant thereof. It might be helpful to replace the $\Bbb W$'s in your question with one of these, or at least add an explanation of what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is! It's called [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus). An example of this is the known formula $\frac{d^a}{dx^a}x^k = \frac{k!}{(k-a)!}x^{k-1}$ which you can see if we apply the gamma function to this we can make sense of non integer cases of $a$. For example when $a=\frac12$ and k = 2 we have $\frac{d^{\frac12}}{dx^{\frac12}}x^2 = \frac{2!}{(3/2)!}x^{\frac32}$ then repeating we get $\frac{2!}{(3/2)!}*\frac{(3/2)!}{1!}x=2x$ which is the normal derivative of $x^2$. There are more general cases where this can be applied, but I'm not too knowledgable about them so you'll have to let someone else show you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a fantastic explanation and I'll definitely look into it!